# Project organization with Cython and C++

Tags: c++, python, build, cython

I want to provide my C++ project with a Python interface. Technically, I have decided to use Cython for wrapping the C++ code. Over time, the entire project is meant to become a Python extension module, but at first, this is highly experimental. Gradually, C++ classes need to be exposed to Python.

My question is how to best organize files and build configurations so that Cython-generated and human-written C++ code do not get mixed and the Python extension module is cleanly built seperate from the other targets.

I imagine a directory structure like this for the source files, and some build directory for Cython.

```
Project/
    src/
        *.h
        *.cpp
    cython/
        Project.pyx
        setup.py
```

Comment: can your C++ project be used without Python? Does it make sense to  create parallel ctypes, cffi -based bindings (to support more targets with different trades off) that provide the same Python interface?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian the project can and should be used without Python (for now). I do not understand your second question.

Comment: Then logically you have two projects: libproject (C++ library) and pyproject (Python module that allows to use libproject from Python). For convience (easier to install from sources and co-develop) you might include libproject inside pyproject. On the second question: ctypes-based bindings might be easier to deploy on multiple Python versions. cffi-based bindings could be used for better Pypy support. For example, `pyinotify` has both ctypes-based and the native extension written in C, `pyzmq` has both cffi and Cython based implementations. Whether you need it depends on your project.

Comment: That's the way. See more details on how I managed the whole stuff in the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically I have 3 folders :

1. `CPROJECT`, The C++ library : producing a `libcproject.so` shared object
2. `CYPROJECT`, The cythonized Python extension : producing the `cyproject.so` using Cython
3. `DEPENDENCIES`, The dependencies : where I copy external requirements for both projects

**In 1.** I build the C++ extension (compiled with gcc - `-shared`, `-fPIC` compile options) that will be exposed to python and that the `CYPROJECT` relies on to expose features to Python. As a post processing command, the resulting `.so` is copied into `DEPENDENCIES/libcproject/` (as well as the `include` files). This way the library is, of course, usable independently in a pure C++ project as well.

**In 2.** I make use of 3 sub-folders :

- `adapters` : which mainly contains C++ additional classes (often classes derived from the ones provided by `libcproject.so`). Those are usually classes that are enhanced with functionalities specific to Cython requirements (such as storing the `PyObject *` C version of a targeted Python version - inherited from `object` - of a given class and the reference counting management, via `Py_XINCREF` and `Py_DECREF`, ...).
- `pyext` : where are stored all the Cython hand written `.pyx` files.
- `setup` : containing the `setup.sh` script (for setting up the dependencies paths and calling the `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` for generating the final `cyproject.so` (to be added to the `PYTHONPATH`) and `cyproject.pyx`.

So what's in the `setup` sub-folder ?

Here is a sample code for `setup.sh` :

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:../../../DEPENDENCIES/Cython-0.18
export PATH=$PATH:../../../DEPENDENCIES/libcproject:../../../DEPENDENCIES/Cython-0.18/bin

# Note the `../../../DEPENDENCIES/libcproject`...

CC="gcc"   \
CXX="g++"   \
    python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

And here an example of `setup.py` (mainly to demonstrate how the additional `adapters` are compiled):

```
import sys
import os
import shutil

from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

# Cleaning
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        if (name.startswith("cyproject") and not(name.endswith(".pyx"))):
            os.remove(os.path.join(root, name))
    for name in dirs:
        if (name == "build"):
            shutil.rmtree(name)

# Building
setup(
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = [
    Extension("cyproject", 
              sources=["cyproject.pyx", \
                       "adapter/ALabSimulatorBase.cpp", \
                       "adapter/ALabSimulatorTime.cpp", \
                       "adapter/ALabNetBinding.cpp", \
                       "adapter/AValueArg.cpp", \
                       "adapter/ALabSiteSetsManager.cpp", \
                       "adapter/ALabSite.cpp", \
                       ],
              libraries=["cproject"],
              language="c++",
              extra_compile_args=["-I../inc", "-I../../../DEPENDENCIES/python2.7/inc", "-I../../../DEPENDENCIES/gsl-1.8/include"], 
              extra_link_args=["-L../lib"]
              extra_compile_args=["-fopenmp", "-O3"],
              extra_link_args=[]
              )
    ]
)
```

And finally, the main `.pyx`, that links all the hand written `.pyx`s of the cython part together [`cyproject.pyx`] :

```
include "pyext/Utils.pyx" 
include "pyext/TCLAP.pyx" 
include "pyext/LabSimulatorBase.pyx"
include "pyext/LabBinding.pyx"
include "pyext/LabSimulatorTime.pyx"
...
```

Note : All the files generated by Cython remains in this `setup` folder, well separated from the hand written stuffs (`adapters` and `pyext`), as expected.

**In 3.** Using a separated `DEPENDENCIES` folder allows to keep things well separated (in case I would move the `CYPROJECT` - and its dependencies - in some other environment).

All of this to give you an overview (a pertinent one, I hope) on how one can organize that sort of project.

Comment: This is quite a specific example, but nonetheless a helpful one.

Comment: But I was thinking that this would match your needs, since the specific parts are that I use a shared C++ library (which you would/should have too) and adapters (which you will need soon or later, I guess).

Comment: Okay, I'll refer to your example as my project grows.