# Do I have to recursively include all headers when wrapping C++ in Cython

Tags: c++, cython, word-wrap

I'm trying to wrap a C++ library using Cython.

The headers themselves include other libraries to define types (actually, quite a lot), somethings like this:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>

namespace abc {
namespace xyz {
typedef Eigen::Matrix<double, 5, 1> Column5;
typedef Column5 States;
}}
```

There are a lot of "external" type definitions. Is there a way **not** to write also a .pxd file for the Eigen library? I just need the type "States" available in my .pxd-file for imported (wrapped) class definitions...

Comment: Do you have the library sources?

Comment: Yes, they are available (in principle). Are the headers sufficient?

Comment: Yes, sorry I had a crazy idea, but I tried it on my machine and it did not work :-(

Comment: @user2055010 No, it won't. You'll also need to link with the Eigen library in some way. See the links in the comment below my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure about what you are asking for, but as far as I understood, I would say: Just expose what you need (here the `State` type).

In your `.pyx` or your `.pxd`:

(Assuming the code in your question is part of a file named `my_eigen.h`)

```
# Expose State 
cdef extern from "some_path/my_eigen.h" namespace "xyz" :
    cdef cppclass States:
        # Expose only what you need here
        pass
```

Once you have done the wrapping above, you are free to use `State` where ever you need it in Cython code.

```
# Use State as is in your custom wrapped class
cdef extern from "my_class_header.h" namespace "my_ns" :
    cdef cppclass MyClassUsingStates:
        double getElement(States s, int row, int col)
        ...
```

Example:

*Here my need was: having a python handler for `std::ofstream` and no need to expose any of its methods (so I exposed none but it would have been possible...)*

```
cdef extern from "<fstream>" namespace "std" :
    cdef cppclass ofstream:
        pass

cdef class Py_ofstream:
    cdef ofstream *thisptr

    def __cinit__(self):
       self.thisptr = new ofstream()

    def __dealloc__(self):
       if self.thisptr:
           del self.thisptr
```

Note : here I used it directly as a single block in my `.pyx` (no additional `.pyd`).

Tell me if misunderstood the question...

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try. Currently I'm struggeling with cython compiling (my setup.py), so it may take a while.

Comment: @user2055010 I already wrote some things that might be useful to you [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16806261/1715716) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16994414/1715716). It may help.

Comment: Thank you for these setup.py's! They are now stored as references ;) because in most "tutorials" you find online, they omit the importand "include_dirs" etc. parts.
 Meanwhile, I managed to get things compiled using the "cythonize" from  Cython.Build .

Comment: Basically, your answer was just right. I was confused because from the tutorials I was convinced that your `cdef`s had to expose _all_ of the C++ module.

Comment: Glad to help. ;) If I can do more, just ask !