# Cython, C++ and gsl

Tags: c++, python, cython, gsl

So I have set up a c++ class with say class.cpp, class.h. class.cpp uses some functions from gsl (it has `#include <gsl/gsl_blas.h>`)
I have no problem linking this to another c++ file main.cpp and I can compile it with

```
g++ -o main main.o class.o  -I/home/gsl/include -lm -L/home/gsl/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas
```

Also, without including the gsl libary in class.cpp, I have managed to create a cython file that uses my class in class.cpp, and it works.

However, when I try to *combine* these two (ie using a c++ class in cython, where the c++ class uses gsl functions), I do not know what to do. I guess I have to include the

```
I/home/gsl/include -lm -L/home/gsl/lib -lgsl -lgslcblas
```

somewhere in the setup file, but I dont know where or how. My setup.py looks like

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

import os

os.environ["CC"] = "g++"
os.environ["CXX"] = "g++"

setup(
    name = "cy",
    ext_modules = cythonize('cy.pyx'),
)
```

and I have

```
# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: sources = class.cpp
```

in the beginning of my .pyx file.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use the `extra_compile_args` option in your extension.
I already wrote some answer that luckily uses `GSL` dependency [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16806261/1715716).

Customize following your needs, but it should work this way.

Hope this can help...

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the required external libraries using the `libraries`, `include_dirs` and `library_dirs` parameters of the `Extension` class. For example:

```
from distutils.extension import Extension
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

myext = Extension("myext",
                  sources=['myext.pyx', 'myext.cpp'],
                  include_dirs=[numpy.get_include(), '/path/to/gsl/include'],
                  library_dirs=['/path/to/gsl/lib'],
                  libraries=['m', 'gsl', 'gslcblas'],
                  language='c++',
                  extra_compile_args=["-std=c++11"],
                  extra_link_args=["-std=c++11"])
setup(name='myproject',
      ext_modules=cythonize([myext]))
```

Here, the C++ class is defined in `myext.cpp` and the cython interface in `myext.pyx`. See also: [Cython Documentation](http://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/reference/compilation.html?highlight=libraries%3D#configuring-the-c-build)